# How xtrabackup restores data to the replica server

Tags: replication, backup, mysql-8.0

The product is a microservice architecture, divided into multiple databases. In order to facilitate the background management program to facilitate cross-database linked list query, a replica server is designed. Part of the configuration of the replica server is as follows

```
replicate-rewrite-db=db1->backend
replicate-rewrite-db=db2->backend
replicate-rewrite-db=db3->backend
replicate-rewrite-db=db4->backend
```

We use xtrabackup to back up multiple databases. If the slave database hangs, can it be restored by backing up the data?